# How do I do some data validation dropdown items can be selectable by only owner of the document?

Tags: google-sheets

I have a Google Sheets document which is shared with nearly thirty people and I added data validation dropdown to all the cells to not entering different values except I defined.

This data validation dropdown has nine items and I want to the fifth, sixth, seventh, eighth and nineth items can be selectable by only owner of the document. Can you please explain how I can do this?

Comment: Please provide a lot more detail of what you are trying to accomplish. You need to specify the language you are using, any frameworks that might affect the answer and what you mean by one person. Is that a logged in user, is that one of multiple users who might be using the system at a time, etc. With so little information provided, nobody will be able to provide you a good answer.

Comment: If both types of users are supposed to be using the spreadsheet at the same time, I don't think there's a way to do that. If that's not the case, maybe a workaround could be found, using Apps Script. Can you please provide more details about your situation?

Answer (score 0):

Depending on what you are trying to do, and how critical the application is, the following trick might **possibly** work for you.

Basically, the data validation list, which can be hidden out of sight (different tab or hidden column) uses formulas to complete some of the values.  And the formula checks for some special value entered at a specific cell in the sheet.  Or even multiple cells if you want to make it more complicated.

In this case, one of the cells in the data validation range has the formula:

```
=IF($B$1=321,"Hidden F","")
```

If the correct value is entered in B1 - in the case, the value is 321 - it "unlocks" the hidden dropdown values, which can now be selected.  This approach might work if the volume of data entry is low.  It would "fail" if a shared user was using the dropdowns at the same time as the owner, who had entered the "authorization" code in B1.  Or if the owner forgot to delete the auth code from B1, when finished.

Another drawback is if any of the users are expected to update the list of dropdown values.

The last drawback is that when the code is deleted from B1, and the data validation values get updated by the formulas, any of the hidden values entered by the owner show a warning message as "Invalid input", but they still remain entered.

Note that this is not a secure approach, but it may be convenient if you just want to keep users from accidentally entering values they shouldn't.

Have a look at [this test sheet](https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1S5bkEVR-CMRBVlhFBoaatD2qptCoIL8noSn8i--mxak/edit?usp=sharing), and see if there is any chance it would work for you.

[image]

Comment: Thanks for your effort but this solution is not good enough. Can't we add something like =IF NOT(user=x, "Hidden F", "") to the data validation list cells? By this way we can get rid of the invalid warning message and auth you thought : )

Comment: By NOT(user=x), do you mean to check the active user (logged in Google account) editing this sheet?  I don't believe that this can be done by formula, only by a script.  And even then, I don't know that it you can obtain account information, except maybe with business google accounts in the same domain.  I'll wait for someone else to propose a solution.